# kotlin multiplateforme to js : generate the package.json

Tags: node.js, kotlin, package.json, kotlin-multiplatform

I use the plugin "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform"
in order to generate a lib both in java and js

Anyone have a snippet of code to build the package.json with all the dependencies ?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Distribute a stand-alone JS library that knows nothing about Kotlin, apart from its implementation?

Comment: yes. Ideally, I want to publish it on npm

Comment: (I don't have the snippet that you're asking for, but it's an interesting problem and I'd gladly welcome a solution for it, too.) IMO it's not officially supported. If we wanted to implement such thing, I wonder what would happen with your project's Kotlin dependencies. They would also have to exist in npm. Another solution is to gather all non-npm dependencies and "embed" them in your app, including e. g. Kotlin runtime. With this second solution, it should be doable: just take the output JS bundle and prepare a package.json that contains no dependencies, just metadata.

Comment: The Kotlin Frontend Plugin creates package.json files. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-frontend-plugin

Comment: I need to use the multi plateform plugin, not the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own in the path `jsMain/resources/package.json`.

This will get added to your processedFiles in the `build` folder